# Formatting Laptop: Unable to format HP laptop after changing its hard disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have changed the hard disk of my HP 630 laptop and now formatting it, but I am unable to format it.

When I format it with Windows 7, it stuck after coping file.
When I format it with Windows 8, it restarts system after welcome screen.

I have replaced the hard disk of HP laptop(`HDD` 500 GB) with a Compaq laptop(`HDD` 320 GB.

I am formatting the HP laptop because after exchanging hard disks my WiFi is not working. Please suggest me what is the solution.

Comment: Is your replacement disk on its way out?

Comment: Yes, all features is working fine except WiFi and Network.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense... What are you trying to do, wipe the drive and start clean, or fix a networking issue? Switching disks between two devices that are not identical often means you need to wipe the drive and reinstall from the correct Windows Recovery disc for ir that computer.

Comment: Ok, Currently I want to format that drive but I am unable to do it.

Comment: What do you mean "unable"? Insert the media and boot off of it, and do a clean windows install or factory recover operation... The format operation is done automatically. If you want to do it manually, you need a Bootable OS on media, like Linux on a USB stick, and use its format tool. You can't format a drive well your booted on that drive.